# Package check was not found in the pkg-config search path

Tags: c, netbeans, homebrew, pkg-config

I am using check package in netbeans for C programming, But I receive this error from netbeans:
Package check was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `check.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'check' found

In the terminal if I insert this line:
    `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`
and then
    `pkg-config --modversion check`
it can find the check package, but in netbeans I still get the same error.
What should I do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: whack it in yer bashrc - the export that is.

Comment: There must be an option in NetBeans to set environment variables for its compiling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use OS X Mavericks,
Then download packages "check", "valgrind", "gcc" and "pkg-config" through the [HomeBrew](http://brew.sh/).
then edit `/etc/launchd.conf` and add there `setenv PATH <your $PATH>` Substitute with your real path. In this file no $HOME or such can't be used. This path should include gcc, check and valgrind. For this to take effect you need to restart your computer.

For me this worked:

```
$ cat /etc/launchd.conf
setenv PATH /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```