# macOS Issue when installing geany plugins

Tags: macos, geany, geany-plugin

I have been trying to install the Geany plugins since yesterday but unsuccessfully.
I am using a mac os Sierra version 10.12.6
I installed Geany 1.31 on my mac.

and here are the steps I follow to install the plugins: 
1- I dowloaded the plugins folder

then on the terminal I type:

```
cd /Users/davidabitbol/Downloads/untitled\ folder/geany-plugins-1.31
```

then

```
./configure
```

and here it does not work. this is what I get:

```
Package geany was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `geany.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'geany' found
checking for GEANY... no
configure: error: Package requirements (geany >= 1.29) were not met:

No package 'geany' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables GEANY_CFLAGS
and GEANY_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

I can't manage to solve this issue. 
Any idea what should be done?

thanks

Comment: It seems pretty self-explanatory to me. `configure` is looking for a `pkg-config` definition for Geany but can't find it. Have you checked whether the copy of Geany you installed provides a `.pc` file, and have you tried adjusting the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable to help the plugins find that `.pc` file?

Comment: How do I check for a .pc file? 
I installed Geany using a .dmg. So i only downloaded the installer, opened and dragged to application.

Comment: Regarding PKG_CONFIG_PATH i have no idea how to adjust this either. 
All I did so far was install many things that were missing. When running the configure it would tell me "can't find ..." So i would install it. Usually by checking on this website how do to do so. Most of the time I used a brew command.

Comment: There are plenty of results for _stackoverflow package not found in pkg-config search path_ on Google, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25632454/package-check-was-not-found-in-the-pkg-config-search-path / https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36578535/package-libusb-was-not-found-in-the-pkg-config-search-path. If your `.dmg` does not seem to provide a `.pc` file, ask its maintainer if there is one, and if there is not, you'll have to provide the alternative solution that `pkg-config` already explained.

Comment: Compiling g-p with macOS is not as easy. Check out https://github.com/geany/geany-osx for some documentation around and how the dmg of Geany is build

Comment: Hi everyone. 
I wanted to thank you all for your help but unfortunately I could not manage to have the plugins installed. No big deal. I run linux on my computer as double boot for some courses at the university, so I installed Geany there. A few minutes and everything worked like a charm. 
I have been following the links you sent me and many others, but as far as I can tell it works for some persons but most have issues when trying to install the plugins... I hope it will be made easier for mac users. 
Any way, thanks for your help